# xref-find-definitions, find next

Tags: tags, xref

In decades past when I used `find-tag`, I think there was a way to advance to the next tag definition if the first one found is not the one you were looking for.
Is there a way to do this now that `find-tag` has been made obsolete by `xref-find-definitions`?

In my particular case I'd like to jump to a Java class definition of type XYZ, but am instead taken to a Java class that has an XYZ member declaration.

GNU Emacs 25.2.1

Answer (score 0):

- `M-x next-error`, or
- `M-g n` (same command), or
- Switch to Xref's window and press `n` (maybe several times). When you see the buffer you're looking for displayed, press `RET`.

Comment: For that command I get "next-error-find-buffer: No buffers contain error message locations"
Also for some reason I don't get an *xref* buffer for XYZ but I do for other tags, which seems weird.

Comment: Try installing the latest version of `xref` from ELPA through `M-x list-packages`. That will bring `next-error` integration, among other things. But regarding `XYZ`, it seems there is only one definition that etags recognizes for it. You can `M-x report-emacs-bug` about that, but first try installing a newer version of Emacs, it might already be fixed.

Comment: The latest Emacs release at the moment is 27.2.